# Is it possible to make a hexagonal drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, gsap

[The grid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFvfH.png)

Is it possible to create a drag and drop system, in which the circular draggable elements would snap to this hexagonal grid presented above, and log the starting and the arriving coordinates? I wanted to solve this by logging the click coordinates and geting the color of the pixel at the same coordinates on a special grid on the server, then decoding the coordinates from the color code, but it would be much more user friendly if it would be possible with drag and drop.

Thanks for your time.

Levente

Comment: "Is it possible" : If you code it, yes.

Comment: The question is: What would you recommend?

Comment: Where should i start looking for a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you represent the hexagons (svg, image, css + rotated divs, canvas, ...) I would use different approaches. If you use SVGs or rotated divs, you can simply use the onmouseover event handler to determine the underlying hexagon. If you use a canvas, you cold convert the cartesian pointer coordinates into cube coordinates using a rotation matrix.

I found a lot of useful coordinate conversions on the following page:
http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates

I don't know which coordinate systems you want to use if you want to use the this approach, nor do I know how you are storing informations related to the hexagon fields. Therefore, I can't give you a complete solution yet, but I hope this informations will help you anyway.

Comment: Thanks. This web page helps a lot. Thank you!